# IDL to Type Library

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, corba, idl, typelib

Is there a way in Delphi 7 to generate a tlb from an idl? Or even from a class/ interface definition?

Comment: again: *what IDL?* idl2pas will process IDL subset used in Visibroker, and will choke on arbitrary (eg MIDL)

Answer (score 2):

you can use the `IDL2PAS.bat` batch file (check in this location C:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi7\Bin) or the [`MIDL.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms690550%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) application.

Comment: ? I was under the impression that IDL2PAS.bat generates the stubs and skeletons for Visibroker specific clients and servers. The midl.exe gives an error that cl.exe can not be found.

Comment: @Asher, re: Visibroker - didnt you add corba tag?

Comment: @Worm, yes I did. Don't understand your question

Comment: In the folder i have IDL2Pas.jar, what do i do with it ? XE2.

Answer (score 1):

In Delphi 7 one of the easiest ways is to copy/paste the IDL into the Type Library editor source window.  NOT the *_TLB.pas source unit 'behind' the type library, but the type library editor itself.

I don't have D7 to hand right now, but iirc you may have to set the "Type Library Language" option in the IDE settings to IDL rather than Pascal.  And I also seem to recall that this technique could be sensitive to "exotic" IDL (i.e. didn't always work), but if the IDL in question is relatively straightforward, this may work for you.