# Programmatically change win10 slideshow settings?

Tags: delphi, windows-10, desktop

I'm using Windows 10 Home Edition and Delphi xe8. I made a program that paints on desktop wallpaper and behind the
icons. I've tried many API functions to inform the slideshow app not to interfere with my program.

Whatever I do, it doesn't notify slideshow - except setting wallpaper. If I set the wallpaper,
I can not reset it back to slideshow programmatically.

I basically want to suspend the slideshow while my program runs. After quitting the program,
slideshow should be resumed. I thought that if I set the "Interval" period long enough, then
change it back to normal (when quitting my program) it would be enough. I  change registry settings (setting interval from 1 min. to 1 day, and vice versa) but slideshow doesn't know about it.
I've tried :

1. `SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, nil, SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE or SPIF_SENDCHANGE);`
2. `SHChangeNotify (SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED, 0, nil, nil);`

But none informs slideshow.

Comment: "I change registry settings (setting interval from 1 min. to 1 day, and viceversa) but slideshow doesn't know about it." Well I would imagine so. Changing registry values is only half of the story. The actual app responsible for the slideshow (Windows Explorer?) needs to re-read these registry settings. I assume it already has those settings cached, so that it doesn't need to keep reading from the registry.

Comment: [IDesktopWallpaper::SetSlideshowOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706961(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: ...and to answer your next question : [How to import IDL into Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27822452/327083)

Comment: I hope you write a good uninstall program

Comment: Thank you J... I am looking for interfaces, but can not find where idesktopwallpaper interface class is defined. Win10-sdk seems to have it, 2.7GB is a bit huge to download. Anyway, thank you again.